# Go lang multiplexing all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go

I wants to create a fan-in function using multiple go routines returning channel here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg, wg2 sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    final := talk(boring("Joe"), boring("Ann"))
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-final)
    }
    fmt.Println("You are both boring I'm leaving")
}

func talk(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    out := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        for {
            out <- <-input1
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        for {
            out <- <-input2
        }
    }()
    wg.Done()
    close(out)
    return out
}

func boring(msg string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s%d\n", msg, i)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1e3)) * time.Millisecond)
    }
    return c
}
```

But I got an error after running above code

> all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

I have tried to close channels but still it is giving me the error. I have tried to assign boring returned channels to Joe and Ann and then pass those channels to talk function for multiplexing still no success. I am new to go learning channels not clear on this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of wait groups, you can use `select`: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5

> The `select` statement lets a goroutine wait on multiple communication
>   operations.
>
> A `select` blocks until one of its cases can run, then it executes that
>   case. It chooses one at random if multiple are ready.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    final := talk(boring("Joe"), boring("Ann"))
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-final)
    }
    fmt.Println("You are both boring I'm leaving")
}

func talk(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case s := <-input1:
                c <- s
            case s := <-input2:
                c <- s
            }
        }
    }()
    return c
}

func boring(msg string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s: %d", msg, i)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1e3)) * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    return c
}
```

[Try it on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sDvYssPIjP)

**Edit:**

In your given example, `boring` function doesn't use goroutine for repeated send over channel which will block forever, because:
https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready.
>   This allows goroutines to synchronize without explicit locks or
>   condition variables.

Also, `wg.Done()` needs to be part of goroutine.

I got it working by doing above changes: https://play.golang.org/p/YN0kfBO6iT

Comment: You are right I can go with Select rather than wait for routines not knowing which is in pipeline. But I wants to know the exact reason of why it is creating deadlock. My main concern was the reason behind my code not working.

Comment: Yeah I have also done it. Since I go through my code again and found I have not used go routine to send value to channel in side boring function. thanks for teh update

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop a goroutine by itself, I suggest signaling the goroutine to quit with something along these lines:

```
stop := make(chan bool)
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case <- stop:
            return
        default:
            // Do other stuff
        }
    }
}()

// Do stuff

// Quit goroutine
stop<- true
```

Comment: I have tried it. But it is not working. I am not getting which go routine is creating deadlock and why?

Comment: In go, non buffered channels will block until something happens on the other end of the channel, regardless of whether you're sending or receiving. So for your case make your channels buffered and this should help. https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3